# Can't enter different hyperlinks into an Excel table?

Tags: excel, power-automate

I'm trying to use Power Automate to enter rows into an Excel table sitting in a OneDrive (existing sheet which already has a table, i.e. a template). One of the columns needs to contain hyperlinks to a PowerApp, with each hyperlink having a GUID passed as a parameter (and as the free-text - see redacted example below).

However, whenever the rows are added (incidentally, either by Power Automate or manually pasted) the autocorrect in Excel changes all the links and text to be "ID1". How can I prevent this? I've tried turning off 'Fill formulas in tables to create calculated columns' in the Proofing>Autocorrect options, and tried selecting 'Stop Automatically Creating Calculated Columns' on the autocorrect popup, but neither option has worked. Tables seem to obey their own rules which can't be altered, it feels.

```
=HYPERLINK("https://apps.powerapps.com/play/e/LINK&transaction=ID1", "ID1")
=HYPERLINK("https://apps.powerapps.com/play/e/LINK&transaction=ID2", "ID2")
=HYPERLINK("https://apps.powerapps.com/play/e/LINK&transaction=ID3", "ID3")
=HYPERLINK("https://apps.powerapps.com/play/e/LINK&transaction=ID4", "ID4")
=HYPERLINK("https://apps.powerapps.com/play/e/LINK&transaction=ID5", "ID5")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fighting it, add a new column for `GUID`, and then have your hyperlink column reference the `GUID` column in the formula.

```
=HYPERLINK("https://apps.powerapps.com/play/e/LINK&transaction=" & [@GUID], [@GUID])
```

You can choose to hide the `GUID` column in your table.

Comment: Did this answer your question?